# Не совпадают отступы у двух Grid объектов с разным количеством внутренних элементов (CSS, grid Layout)

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

Пытаюсь решить такую задачу:
Есть два идентичных объекта Grid CSS, в которых в строчку располагаются разное количество элементов, в одном 5 во втором 2. Нужно, чтобы совпали отступы.

Во втором объекте применил ширину единицами fr, что по логике должно разбить на такое же количество столбцов, что и первый объект, однако отступы между элементами не совпадают с первым объектом.

```css
.tabs-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(20px, 100%));
}
.tabs-grid--two-tabs {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(160px, 2fr) minmax(160px, 3fr);
}
```

Вот пример:
https://codepen.io/2seem/pen/QWWmbma

Comment: Я так понимаю проблема в том, как высчитывается единица измерения `fr`. Ожидается, что `3fr` эквивалентно `1fr + gap + 1fr + gap + 1fr`, и тогда отступы у первого и второго объекта совпали бы.

Answer (score 0):

grid-column-gap: 20px; - Определяет отступ между колонками.

Comment: Это да, и размер отступов совпадает у обоих объектов, свойства полностью идентичны. Однако у второго объекта отступ между внутренними элементами сдвинут относительно первого объекта.